# Dell XPS 13 9350: Where can I switch off Intel Rapid Start & Smart Connect on the latest BIOS?

Tags: bios, dell-xps

This is driving me crazy. I've been struggling for 30 minutes to find Intel Rapid Start and Intel Smart Connect options in my Dell's BIOS. I'm trying to install Ubuntu and some users recommend these be turned off. I want to take all measures before I proceed. Unfortunately, for the life of me, I can't find those things anywhere in the BIOS.

I have BIOS 1.4.4 but I'd be grateful if you check whatever version you have (if you have the same model as me of course).

Somebody recommended I turn on "USB wake support" in BIOS to see IRST. No such luck.

Also, some Forum posts refer to the "Advanced" page in BIOS. There is no such page in my BIOS :(. It's true that the Forum posts in question seem to be about the previous generation Dell.

How can I turn these off for my Dell? Particularly Intel "Smart Connect" seems like a Smart Spyware solution to me and I'd like to give it the boot. Although, conveniently, apparently I can't?

Comment: All Dell consumer bios's do not allow advanced bios features to be accessed. Only business grade PC's allow you to enter advanced bios features.

Comment: So sweet of them to protect us consumers from ourselves. I've been loving this Dell machine otherwise, but this is just sad. Anyway, thanks! :)

Comment: This is common on all consumer PC's, I agree it sucks, but they do it to cut down on support calls due to average users making changes in the bios.